# Iam not able to retrieve completely the data from sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

```
public string getString()
{

  con.ConnectionString = ConnString;
  con.Open();
  string sp = "select top 3 hotelid from hotel order by NEWID()";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp, con);

  SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read()) //Call Read to move to next record returned by SQL //OR call --While(reader.Read()) 
  {
    det  = reader[0].ToString();

  }
  reader.Close();
  con.Close();
  return det;
}
```

When I'm executing this code I'm able to retrieve only a single item of data?,
but when I am executing the SQL query I am able to retrieve randomly 3 items of data.

Comment: Where have defined det and its overriding for every row and fetching only the last row from the while loop

Comment: after string concatenation , its retrieving all the 3 data,but its showing the result  in a single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `det` variable on each `while` loop.

You either need to create a collection and add to it, or concatenate the string (note the `+=`)...

```
det += reader[0].ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested above, another option is to create a collection, something like...

```
public List<string> getString()
{
  ...
  List<string> ret = new List<string>;
  while (reader.Read())
    ret.Add(reader[0].ToString());
  ...
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: after string concatenation , its retrieving all the 3 data,but its showing it in a single string

Comment: @user1194078 - what do you expect? You're asking a function to return 3 pieces of information from a single string return variable. We're showing you why only one piece of information is being returned... it's up to you to work out *how* your function deals with it. Think about the option of returning either a concatenated string with character delimiters, or maybe a string array, etc

Comment: @user1194078 - had any luck getting what you need?

Comment: I have return the data with the concatenated string with character delimiters and its working fine

Comment: @user1194078 - good, I'm glad you've got it working, well done :-)